# Is there any way to do argument-checking in an elemental function?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

### Example

Suppose I want to write an elemental function that checks its arguments, as in the following toy example:

```
elemental real function square_root( x )
    real, intent(IN) :: x
    if (x<0) then
        print *, "Error in square_root(): the variable x must be non-negative."
        stop 1
    endif
    square_root = sqrt(x)
end function square_root
```

### Motivation

Marking a procedure as `elemental` allows a flexible syntax: I can call it with a scalar or with a multi-dimensional array with no change in calling syntax. This is awesome.

Checking argument values is generally a good practice and has helped me greatly in the past.

### Difficulty

This example would not compile because `elemental` procedures must also be `pure` procedures, and neither I/O nor program terminations are permitted in `pure` procedures.

It appears that I can do either one of the following, but not both:

- Make a function check its inputs and throw some kind of error/exception
- Mark a function as `elemental`

### Question

**Is there *any* way to get the flexible syntax provided by `elemental` while also checking argument values?**

I'm happy to use features of newer Fortran standards and/or invoke polymorphism (e.g. via an interface) if necessary/possible, though I  hope there's an easier way!

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to avoid signalling errors or exceptional situations in the arguments (for a subroutine) or function result (for a function)<sup>1</sup> then there are options:

- from Fortran 2008 elemental procedures need not be pure;
- from Fortran 2018 error termination prompted by an `error stop` statement may commence in a pure subprogram<sup>2</sup>.

An elemental function which is not pure may be specified with the `impure` prefix:

```
impure elemental function can_io_stdout(x)
  ..
  print *, "Hello!"
end function
```

For Fortran 2018 (to be published):

```
elemental function can_terminate(x)
  ..
  error stop "Termination from a pure function"
end function
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, one may choose to return a NaN in the case of the square root of a real.

<sup>2</sup> As IanH notes, error termination may come about in pure procedures by means other than `error stop` even in earlier language revisions.

Comment: Nit - F2008 permitted error termination in a pure program too (and effectively F2003 did, using different words).  What F2018 will permit is the use of the error stop statement to initiate that error termination.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this point allows the processor to terminate the program in pure procedures due to "normal" errors like array shape mismatch in an assignment or invalid format string in an internal I/O?

Comment: @VladimirF, with a shape mismatch that's a program deviation so not covered by the standard.  I/O error termination was what I though of when seeing IanH's comment.

Comment: As an example, attempting to ALLOCATE an already allocated variable (e.g. `INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: x ; ALLOCATE(x) ; ALLOCATE(x)`) initiates error termination in F2008 - see 6.7.1.3p1 bullet 1 and 6.7.1.2p9.  You could also deallocate an unallocated allocatable for the same outcome.  Nothing in F2008 prohibits this sort of stuff in a pure procedure.  A similar situation exists in earlier revisions of the language, but there is no concept of error termination.  Permitting ERROR STOP in PURE procedures lets you do this nicely.